# How do I create a journaled ext4 partition on /dev/sdb1 with journal data on /dev/sda4

Tags: gparted, ext4

I have a ubuntu OS, on a 256GB SSD with 150GB free raw disk left on /dev/sda and I want to add a new 8TB drive (/dev/sdb) as ext4/journaled but place the journal data on a new partition on /dev/sda, I found one link via google search but it just talks about **tune2fs** not the entire process.

I am trying to figure out the correct steps/process to do this, I would like to use **Gparted** for most of this work. I have searched the net but can not find end to end process.

- What is the correct command to create a new partition (eg. /dev/sda4)
  for journal data to be written to (mount point name, lable etc) and
  how do I use **mke2fs**, does it need to have an entry in /etc/fstab?,
  will it be mounted?, will it need UUID? etc..
- What is the syntax of the command "**mkfs.ext4**" for /dev/sdb1 so the entire 8TB is one large
  partition called /data and is journaled or the options in "**gparted**"?
  Do I need to use the command "tune2fs"? etc...
- How do I link (**mke2fs**) the journaling for /dev/sdb1 (/data) partition onto /dev/sda4? Many
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a few trial Ubuntu OS install & reinstall and filesystem alteration.  My installed Ubuntu OS was on /dev/sda1, /dev/sda4, /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6, so I created a new **2GB** partition as **primary** using gparted (**ext2** type) and configured the mount point as /jfslog ( /dev/sda2 ).  I did not added anything to /etc/fstab since this 2G partition was not going to be a normal partition and soon was going to be modified.

I used this command to change the 2GB partition to the journal log area

```
sudo mke2fs -O journal_dev /dev/sda2
```

I used gparted and create a new 8TB **ext4** type partition with mount point of /data which had **/dev/sdb1** as its raw device locator

Using this command I removed the journaling from the new 8b TB ext4 filesystsem (since by default the ext4 gets configured with journaling) and then re-added it back in as external based journaling using /dev/sda2 on the SSD drive as journaling device.

```
sudo tune2fs -O \^has_journal /dev/sdb1     
sudo tune2fs -o journal_data -j -J device=/dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1
```

after this was done, I used the below command to get the UUID of the /data and added it to /etc/fstab file for automatic mounting at boot time.

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1
```

**PS**, *I am not using any virtualization like vSphere etc... this was a standalone OS on a none virtualized hardware.*